Completeness of vector field generated by family of diffeomorphisms
Let $M$ be a smooth manifold. Let $I$ be an open interval containing zero. A smooth family of diffeomorphisms (parameterised by $I$) is a smooth map $\varphi:I \times M \rightarrow M$ such that $\varphi(t,-):M \rightarrow M$ is a diffeomorphism for all $t \in I$ and $\varphi(0,-) = \text{Id}_M$.
Let $\varphi:I \times M \rightarrow M$ be smooth family of diffeomorphisms, and define
$$X_p := \frac{d}{dt}\bigg|_{t=0}\varphi(t,p).$$
Then it is straightforward to check that the map $X:M \rightarrow TM$ given by $p \mapsto X_p$ is a smooth vector field. We call $X$ the vector field generated by $\varphi$.
Question. If $\varphi:I \times M \rightarrow M$ is a smooth family of diffeomorphisms, then is the vector field generated $\varphi$ a complete vector field?
By a complete vector field, I mean a vector field whose maximal integral curves exist for all time.
I suspect that the answer to the question is no, but I have been unable to come up with a counter example. I know that $d/dx$ is not complete on $\mathbb R^+$ and $x^2d/dx$ is not complete on $\mathbb R$, but I am unable to come up with smooth families of diffeomorphisms (as defined above) which generate either vector field.
I know that if $\varphi$ is a flow (as defined in Lee's Smooth Manifolds Chapter 9), then we are done by the Uniform Time Lemma (Lemma 9.15 of Lee's Smooth Manifolds). I am interested in the case when $\varphi$ is not a flow.

How about this? Define $\varphi\colon \mathbb R\times \mathbb R \to \mathbb R$ by
$$
\varphi(t,x) = x + tx^2 + t^2 x^3.
$$
Then for each $t$, $\varphi_t$ is a cubic with positive $x$-derivative everywhere, so it's a diffeomorphism. The vector field $X$ determined by this family is exactly the incomplete vector field $x^2 d/dx$ on $\mathbb R$.

Thank you very much for this answer, it is exactly what I was looking for. What was your method of finding the counterexample?

I first thought of looking for a smooth map whose $t$-derivative at $t=0$ was the incomplete vector field $x^2 d/dx$. The simplest thing to try was a polynomial in $t$. That led me to $\varphi(t,x) = x+tx^2$, but that's not a diffeomorphism when $t\ne 0$. So then I thought of adding a cubic term in $x$ to make each map $\varphi_t$ an invertible cubic polynomial instead of a quadratic, and I figured if I put a $t^2$ in front of the cubic term it wouldn't change the $t$-derivative at $t=0$. Luckily, the first cubic term I tried worked.
